Coordinate system in Visual Studio VB.net Windows Form App extremely weird?
My goal is to use DrawLine method to create lines.
This method has arguments Pen, x1, y1, x2, y2
Pen is the pen with which the line shall be drawn
(x1, y1) Start point
(x2, y2) End point
Here is my code (Form size is 400,400):
Public Class Form1

    Dim grcForm As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim penReg As Pen = New Pen(Brushes.Black, 10)


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        grcForm.DrawLine(penReg, 0, 0, 400, 400)
    End Sub

End Class

However, rather than the line being drawn from the edge of the form to the other edge, this is what I get: (https://i.sstatic.net/vL88P.png)
I also attempted at finding the (400,400) point on the form and surprisingly, ITS OUTSIDE THE FORM (https://i.sstatic.net/TDb3X.png)
Keep in mind that this is a completely new project!
My teacher claims that VS has a weird coordinate system that is off!
Already mentioned previously with code.

This has nothing to do with a weird coordinate system. You're neglecting the fact that the window has borders around it, as well as a title bar. 400x400 is the outside dimension, not the inner one. You're restricted to a smaller area inside that, which is known as the "client rectangle", which is a smaller box inside the window itself. That's the area where your code is drawing, and the point at 400, 400 is off the edge of the window.

For some links that will help you understand the client rectangle, I did a search for you on https://www.google.com/search?q=getclientrect

per @Ken White you can use Me.ClientSize to get size of the inside "drawable" surface

The only weird thing about the coordinate system is that (0, 0) is at the top-left and so y-values increase downwards.
